# 3 dimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am tryng to put together a 3D array, it should build a several arrays that has the car make, its VIN & it's colour. I didn't include the 3rd dimension function, to keep it simple. However, I only get the first digit of VIN when I execute an echo at the end:

```
$table=array("Honda", "Hyundai", "BMW");
while ($x < count($table)) {

// Get the vins for that specific car - multiple returns 
$sql = "SELECT VIN FROM cars WHERE cars='$table[$x]'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // This should create the 2nd dimension, with the car make and its VIN 
        $table[$x][$y]=$row['VIN'];
        //  echo $table[$x][$y].'<br>';
            $y++;
        }
    }

$x++;
$y=0;
}
```

And here I check for a specific array to make sure it works.

```
echo $table[1][2];
```

Comment: Can you show a little more of the surrounding code and how the counters are working? $y appears to be undefined when called in the WHILE loop.

Comment: sorry it posted by mistake. I have edited the post

Comment: My advice would be for you to drop this idea of a 3D array, and prefer creating a class that will generate objects. It's much cleaner this way

Comment: multidim arrays are nearly uncontrollable. Often it is much simpler to use a 1dim array and define the lengths of the dimensions i.e. three dimensions k,l,m: `idx=x+l*y+(l*m)*z` where 0<=x<k, 0<=y<l, 0<=z<m. You could call x columns, y lines and z pages. You can extent this model for any dimension and it works not worse than multidim arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$table=array("Honda", "Hyundai", "BMW");
```

Is not a multi dimensional array so when you do this:

```
$table[$x][$y]=$row['VIN'];
```

You not accessing the second level of array, you are overwriting a character of a string which would be the car make in your case.

---

What about this approach:

```
$table = array();
$makes=array("Honda", "Hyundai", "BMW");
foreach($makes as $make){
    $sql = "SELECT VIN FROM cars WHERE cars='$make'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $car = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $car['vin']=$row['VIN'];
            $car['make']=$make;
        }
        array_push($table, $car);
    }
}

var_dump($table);//all the cars
var_dump($table[0]);//first car
var_dump($table[1]['vin']);//second car vin #
var_dump($table[2]['make']);//third car make
```

Comment: when you want to create an array, than you need to create an array: `$table[$x]=array($row['VIN');` now $table[$x] is an array.

Comment: So any idea how I can "access" the second and 3rd D? Can I define $table[0][0][0]=0; and initialize 3 D array and then start updating the different levels?

Comment: @meda Interesting, but I am not sure if I can access an specific block. Let say if I was looking for the 2nd block of the 1st array, can just call echo $table[1][2]; ?

Comment: @user1622997 what does table mean  in your code, is it a single car or an array of cars

Comment: @meda no it's an array, so like "a table of all the cars in the inventory" so it has 3D that would have all the cars in it.

Comment: @user1622997 check my edit, what you really need is a 2 dimensional array